# Removing padding and margins in template for mobile view but not for desktop view in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have downloaded a template for designing a website, which contains all HTML files and CSS. I want to add some custom padding and margins according to my needs for the desktop view. But I don't want those in mobile view because that is not getting responsive. The CSS file that came with the template already have @media screen defined. I tried adding

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .row{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        }
}
```

but this does not work in css nor in the HTML file itself. How can I remove my forced padding and margins when opened in mobile view for ready made templates?

Comment: Check in developer tools of browser if they are using "!important" for margin and padding and check if you have added your css file after template's css files.

Comment: If there is any parenting class coming then you have to use that class too or you can check in developer tools of browser which css is coming for desktop and mobile on the basis of that you have to write css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extending the padding and margin selector to include `html`, `body` and `*`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   *, html, body, .row {
      margin-left:0 !important;
      margin-right:0 !important;
      padding-left:0 !important;
      padding-right:0 !important;
   }
}
```

A common characteristic of browsers is that `html` and `body` will automatically insert margin spacing around your page if you do not specifically set it to `0` via CSS.

The CSS you provided is quite complex so it's not clear exactly what else is causing the issue, however by adding the above to the bottom of your CSS, this should remove horizontal padding/spacing throughout your page on mobile devices.

Comment: It is not working. Here is the main CSS file. Can you tell where to add these lines exactly? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nedob1dhxwQ4hJYUtW_Zwj1kOVsnfFp1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @PikuBhattacharjee do the above changes help?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot @Dacre Denny.